# Difference between an interrupt and a page fault

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

In operating systems, what is the difference between a page fault and an interrupt? I know that page fault is when the MMU(Memory Management Unit) cannot find the allocated location in the virtual memory

Comment: A page fault is always an _exception_, an _error_, which isn't the case for an interrupt.

Comment: @ForceBru A page fault is not *always* an error, the page could have been swapped out and the OS can service the page fault by swapping in and mapping the page.

Comment: Two answer your question as briefly as possible - A page fault is one of the many interrupts that can be created by the hardware.

Answer (score 13):

Processors are designed to handle two special types of events.

1. Exceptions
2. Interrupts

Both are handled in the same way. Each exception and interrupt known to the CPU has a number. This number is used as an index into a dispatch table of handler routines maintained by the operating system. When the exception or interrupt occurs, the CPU enters kernel mode then locate the corresponding handler routine and invokes it. (Hopefully, the handler will returns to whatever mode the system was in prior to the event).

The difference between an exception and an interrupt is that the former are triggered by the instruction stream and the latter are triggered by events independent of the instruction stream.

Exceptions fall into two categories: faults and traps. The former allow the current instruction to be restarted while the latter do not.

A page fault is then an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Page fault and interrupts are two distincts concepts.

From the [OSdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page):

> A page fault exception is caused when a process is seeking to access an area of virtual memory that is not mapped to any physical memory, when a write is attempted on a read-only page, when accessing a PTE or PDE with the reserved bit or when permissions are inadequate.

And concerning interrupts:

> An interrupt is a signal from a device, such as the keyboard, to the CPU, telling it to immediately stop whatever it is currently doing and do something else. For example, the keyboard controller sends an interrupt when a key is pressed.

So basically, a page fault is an error, an interrupt is a signal and you can use an interrupt to detect a page fault.

For more information on the subject:

- [Page Faults - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Faults)
- [Interrupts - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts)

Comment: Page fault is not necessarily an error. It is just an indication from the hardware that the required Virtual address is not mapped in the page table. The page could simply have been swapped out. In that case the OS can service the page fault and the execution cant continue as if nothing happened in other words, no error.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say a page fault is **always** an error, I said "basically" to explain easily to the op the main idea behind a page fault ;)

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean now. You meant an error from the hardware. Not an error to the program.